# Importing Python Flask JSON dictionary into javascript error

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I have a Python Flask web app that I want to pass a dictionary data set from to javascript, I am trying to JSON I can pass numbers fine but it seems to throw an error when using strings.

Here is the code snippet of the python generating the JSON string:
view.py

---

```
def dumpdata():
DB_name={"name":"aaragh"}  
strng=json.dumps(DB_name)
return render_template('dumpdata.html',result = strng)
```

Here is the receiving HTML file
dumpdata.html

---

```
<html><body>
<p >{{ result }}</a>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse({{result}});
console.log(data.name);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Here is the error message and the console output:
consolelog

---

SyntaxError: invalid property id dumpdata:4

```
<html><body>
<p >{&#34;name&#34;: &#34;aaragh&#34;}</a>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse({&#34;name&#34;: &#34;aaragh&#34;});
console.log(data.name);
</script>
</body></html>
```

I dont think it's relevant but I get the same error on both ubuntu chrome and win IE.

Any ideas? I think I am missing something obvious but I have banged my head against this for days and I still haven't been able to find a solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the template filter `|safe`:

```
<html><body>
<p >{{ result|safe }}</a>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse({{ result|safe }});
console.log(data.name);
</script>
</body></html>
```

[Flask docs mention](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters)
[Jinja docs mention](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping)

Comment: Thanks, I applied your suggestion to include the template filter |safe and the code works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = JSON.parse({{ result|safe }});
```

This line should be changed to

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{ result|safe }}');
```

PS: It didnt work for me without quotes. Also i read it somewhere that in javascript all {{ variable }} are accessible inside quotes only.

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked for me, translating the dictionary with Python and pass that to Javascript to work with...

```html
<script>
  {# passing diffData to javascript in the page template #}

  let diffData = {{ diffData | tojson | safe }};
  console.log(diffData);

  ...the rest of the code...
</script>
```

So I had to pass the `diffData` dictionary to the template and parse the dictionary with Javascript to display the result in a specific format.

I've tried `let diffData = JSON.parse({{ diffData | safe }});` with and without quotes, both types, but Chromium kept throwing errors like:

- `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`
- `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`
- `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Worth noting that I use single-quotes in my dictionary, like:

```py
{'2019-10-08 11:21': {'2019-10-08': {'KSML': {...
```

Hope this helps some out there.

Cheers!